# Filtering spam and valid emails in Python

Tags: python

I must count the number of spam and valid emails in a given list of email ids.

Valid domains are isc.edu and cpp.edu, while the rest are spam.
I must return the count of valid ids and spam ids.
The input email_ids is a list of emails: ex: [ “zrdd@cpp.edu”, “werty@icloud.com”, “example@isc.edu”, “gist@yahoo.com”, “comsc600@cpp.edu” ]

```
def email_filter(email_ids: list) -> (int,int):
    valid = 0
    for emails in email_ids:
        cpp = emails.split('cpp')
        isc = emails.split('isc')
        not_valid = len(cpp) + len(isc)
    else:
        valid = valid + 1
    return valid, not_valid
```

Any suggestions? I only got partial credit on the autograder

Comment: What does `email_ids` look like?

Comment: @InSync email_ids is a list of emails which is also a str. ex: [ “zrdd@cpp.edu”, “werty@yahoo.com”, “example@isc.edu”, “gist@gmail.com”,
“comsc600@cpp.edu” ]

Comment: As a side note: `(int,int)` isn't standard type annotation (though your IDE may introduce it as an extension). If you want this to work with standard type checkers, use `tuple[int, int]`. You might also want to fill in `list`'s generic parameter, e.g. `list[str]`

Answer (score 0):

If email_ids is a list of strings, you can use the `in` condition directly:

```
count_spam = 0
count_not_spam = 0
for email in emails:
    if ('isc.edu' in email) or ('cpp.edu' in email):
        count_not_spam += 1
    else:
        count_spam += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the valid domain occurs at the end of the email address, so that (for example) `isc.edu@yahoo.com` doesn't pass. Also, you only need to count the valid emails, the non-valid emails are simply what's left. You can make use of [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/):

```py
def email_filter(email_ids: list[str]) -> tuple[int,int]:
    valid = sum(email.endswith('cpp.edu') or email.endswith('isc.edu') for email in email_ids)
    return valid, len(email_ids) - valid
    
print(email_filter([ "zrdd@cpp.edu", "werty@yahoo.com", "example@isc.edu", "gist@gmail.com", "comsc600@cpp.edu" ]))
```

Output:

```
(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for emails in email_ids:
    cpp = emails.split('cpp')
    isc = emails.split('isc')
    not_valid = len(cpp) + len(isc)
else:
    valid = valid + 1
```

This loop has three problems.

First, when you call `emails.split('cpp')` on an address that **does** contain "cpp", it returns a list of **two** items -- the part before "cpp", and the part after.  So you're overcounting.

Second, when you call `emails.split('cpp')` on an address that **doesn't** contain "cpp", it returns a list of one item.  So you're still overcounting.

Third, the `else` at the end probably isn't doing what you think.  That code is executed **only once**, after the `for` loop is completely finished.

Why are you using `for/else` anyway?  It's valid python, but it's not typical for beginners.  What did you think the `else` was doing?

Did you actually run this code and test it yourself with a sample list of email addresses?